# Как указывать action у вебформы в asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

У меня возникла проблема с элементарной отправкой post запроса. Пока я гуглил, еще больше запутался. То расширения .aspx , то cshtml. У меня уже мозг кипит.

У меня есть модель users. Эта модель содержит следующие свойства: Name и LastName

```
class Users
{
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set }
}
```

Так же в контролере UsersController существует метод RegisterUser, который в качестве параметра принимает объект класа Users

```
 public ActionResult RegisterUser(Users user)
 {
   //какие-то действия з БД и т.д.
   return View("Registration completed");
 }
```

Так же существует некая форма:

```html
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="Name">
<input type="text" name="LastName">
<input type="Submit">Register</input>
</form>
```

Я не знаю, что мне прописывать в свойство action для того, что бы функция RegisterUser была вызвана.

Comment: На en so похожий вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15190929/5752652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно веб-формы на asp.net mvc не пишут в html-коде, а используют хелперы.

В вашем случае представление формы будет выглядеть так:

```
@model Users

@using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterUser", "Users", new { }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)
    <button type="submit">Register</button>
}
```

Почитайте в документации про параметры BeginForm (actionName/controllerName/etc) и подберите наиболее подходящую перегрузку.

Впрочем, если очень хочется plain html - можете использовать @Url.Action:

```
<form method="post" action="@Url.Action("RegisterUser", "Users")">
    <input type="text" name="Name">
    <input type="text" name="LastName">
    <input type="Submit">Register</input>
</form>
```

Comment: А почему лучше использовать хелперы, а не html код?\

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000 Этот 'mvc way' даёт готовую типизацию полей (автокомплит при написании, удобство при рефакторинге). Но это просто ещё один способ, предложенный майкрософт, они же от него позже отказались в asp.net core - там подход снова поменялся, совершив крен обратно в сторону хэтэмээлизации, сохранив к счастью типизацию.